# How to handle a not defined value in JavaScript 

Tags: javascript

How to handle a not defined value in JavaScript?

```
if (oldins == ins)
```

`oldins` is not defined.

How do I check this?

Comment: You may also want to use the *strict equality operator*, http://www.webreference.com/js/column26/stricteq.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
if ((typeof(oldins) !== "undefined") && (oldins === ins))
```

Comment: +1 for being the right answer. Btw, no need for the parentheses around the `oldins` in the `typeof` check: `typeof` is an operator, not a function.

Answer (score 3):

Unset variables would evaluate to a value of 'undefined'. 'undefined' is a value type like null and NaN so it would be:

```
if ( typeof(oldins) == 'undefined' )
```

Edit: Fixed per comments. Leaving the answer since the comments are helpful, but there were more correct answers.

Comment: Well `undefined` is not exactly like `null` or `NaN` - it's just an identifier and it can be reassigned!

Comment: This will give you an error if `oldins` has never been declared. Use `typeof` instead.

Comment: @Pointy: Actually, `NaN` is also a variable as is `Infinity` - both can be reassigned. `null` is the only true keyword among these.

Comment: @casablanca wow really?  Well after I typed in that comment I was going to try those but I got distracted, so thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (oldins !== undefined && oldins === ins) {

}
```

Comment: This will give you an error if `oldins` has never been declared. Use `typeof` instead.